# lxc-start does not work in a cron script

Tags: cron, lxc

This script runs fine in the console, but fails to start the container in cron. So, lxc-stop will work fine in cron, but lxc-start won't

The cron message I receive is `lxc-start wait_on_daemonized_start: 833 No such file or directory - Failed to receive the container state`

```
for CONTAINER in $(lxc-ls -1 | grep data); do
    lxc-stop --name=$CONTAINER
    sleep 2
    lxc-start --daemon --name=$CONTAINER
done
```

Any idea why it is only start that is failing in cron?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.
The solution was to add the necessary PATH to cron.
For me it was PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
and then lxc-start did work.
Hope it helps!